# Using LAG() function to get the previous row value in SQL/BigQuery but still incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, google-bigquery

I used the below query to retrieve the desired table:

```
with

PairingActivityInPairing AS (
SELECT  DISTINCT
    P.Id AS PairingId,
    PD.Id AS PairingDutyId,
    PA.Id AS PairingActivityId,
    E.Id AS EmployeeId,
    PEV.PairingEventTypeId,
    PEV.StartDate AS PEStartDate,
    FF.ArrivalActual AS FFArrival,
    TZ.ZuluOffset
FROM
   <my_table>
ORDER BY
   P.Id, PD.Id, PA.Id
```

| PairingId | PairingDutyId | PairingActivityId | EmployeeId | PairingEventTypeId | PEStartDate | FFArrival | ZuluOffset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 682 | 247907 | 10 | null | null | 2021-06-18 15:18:00 | null |
| 2010 | 682 | 247908 | 10 | null | null | 2021-06-18 20:15:00 | null |
| 2010 | 682 | 247909 | 10 | 8 | 2021-06-18 19:55:00 | null | 9.0 |
| 2010 | 683 | 247910 | 10 | null | null | 2021-06-20 01:55:00 | null |
| 1946 | 980 | 225388 | 3 | null | null | 2022-03-01 19:28:00 | null |
| 1946 | 980 | 225389 | 3 | 8 | 2023-03-01 19:40:00 | null | 9.0 |
| 1946 | 981 | 225390 | 3 | null | null | 2022-03-03 02:31:00 | null |

And I want to get the previous FFArrival of each row PARTITION BY PairingId, PairingDutyId

I tried to add the LAG() function in the query as below:

```
with

PairingActivityInPairing AS (
SELECT  DISTINCT
    P.Id AS PairingId,
    PD.Id AS PairingDutyId,
    PA.Id AS PairingActivityId,
    E.Id AS EmployeeId,
    PEV.PairingEventTypeId,
    PEV.StartDate AS PEStartDate,
    FF.ArrivalActual AS FFArrival,
    LAG(FF.ArrivalActual) OVER (PARTITION BY P.Id, PD.Id ORDER BY PA.Id) AS LagFFArrival,
    TZ.ZuluOffset
FROM
   <my_table>
ORDER BY
   P.Id, PD.Id, PA.Id
```

However, the queried result is not the same as expected one

| PairingId | PairingDutyId | PairingActivityId | EmployeeId | PairingEventTypeId | PEStartDate | FFArrival | LagFFArrival | ZuluOffset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 682 | 247907 | 10 | null | null | 2021-06-18 15:18:00 | 2021-06-18 15:18:00 | null |
| 2010 | 682 | 247908 | 10 | null | null | 2021-06-18 20:15:00 | 2021-06-18 15:18:00 | null |
| 2010 | 682 | 247909 | 10 | 8 | 2021-06-18 19:55:00 | null | null | 9.0 |
| 2010 | 683 | 247910 | 10 | null | null | 2021-06-20 01:55:00 | 2021-06-20 01:55:00 | null |
| 1946 | 980 | 225388 | 3 | null | null | 2022-03-01 19:28:00 | 2022-03-01 19:28:00 | null |
| 1946 | 980 | 225389 | 3 | 8 | 2023-03-01 19:40:00 | null | null | 9.0 |
| 1946 | 981 | 225390 | 3 | null | null | 2022-03-03 02:31:00 | 2022-03-03 02:31:00 | null |

It simply copies the value of FFArrival and my expected result would be below

| PairingId | PairingDutyId | PairingActivityId | EmployeeId | PairingEventTypeId | PEStartDate | FFArrival | LagFFArrival | ZuluOffset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 682 | 247907 | 10 | null | null | 2021-06-18 15:18:00 | null | null |
| 2010 | 682 | 247908 | 10 | null | null | 2021-06-18 20:15:00 | 2021-06-18 15:18:00 | null |
| 2010 | 682 | 247909 | 10 | 8 | 2021-06-18 19:55:00 | null | 2021-06-18 20:15:00 | 9.0 |
| 2010 | 683 | 247910 | 10 | null | null | 2021-06-20 01:55:00 | null | null |
| 1946 | 980 | 225388 | 3 | null | null | 2022-03-01 19:28:00 | null | null |
| 1946 | 980 | 225389 | 3 | 8 | 2023-03-01 19:40:00 | null | 2022-03-01 19:28:00 | 9.0 |
| 1946 | 981 | 225390 | 3 | null | null | 2022-03-03 02:31:00 | null | null |

Please help me to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: The LAG is performed before distinct, could it be that you need to perform it after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE PairingActivity (
    PairingId INT,
    PairingDutyId INT,
    PairingActivityId INT,
    EmployeeId INT,
    PairingEventTypeId INT,
    PEStartDate DATETIME,
    FFArrival DATETIME,
    ZuluOffset DECIMAL(5, 2)
);


INSERT INTO PairingActivity (PairingId, PairingDutyId, PairingActivityId, EmployeeId, PairingEventTypeId, PEStartDate, FFArrival, ZuluOffset)
VALUES
    (2010, 682, 247907, 10, NULL, NULL, '2021-06-18 15:18:00', NULL),
    (2010, 682, 247908, 10, NULL, NULL, '2021-06-18 20:15:00', NULL),
    (2010, 682, 247909, 10, 8, '2021-06-18 19:55:00', NULL, 9.0),
    (2010, 683, 247910, 10, NULL, NULL, '2021-06-20 01:55:00', NULL),
    (1946, 980, 225388, 3, NULL, NULL, '2022-03-01 19:28:00', NULL),
    (1946, 980, 225389, 3, 8, '2023-03-01 19:40:00', NULL, 9.0),
    (1946, 981, 225390, 3, NULL, NULL, '2022-03-03 02:31:00', NULL);

  
WITH PairingActivityInPairing AS (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(FFArrival) OVER (PARTITION BY PairingId, PairingDutyId ORDER BY PairingActivityId) AS LagFFArrival
    FROM PairingActivity
)
SELECT *
FROM PairingActivityInPairing
ORDER BY PairingId desc
```

| PairingId | PairingDutyId | PairingActivityId | EmployeeId | PairingEventTypeId | PEStartDate | FFArrival | ZuluOffset | LagFFArrival |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 682 | 247907 | 10 | *null* | *null* | 2021-06-18 15:18:00.000 | *null* | *null* |
| 2010 | 682 | 247908 | 10 | *null* | *null* | 2021-06-18 20:15:00.000 | *null* | 2021-06-18 15:18:00.000 |
| 2010 | 682 | 247909 | 10 | 8 | 2021-06-18 19:55:00.000 | *null* | 9.00 | 2021-06-18 20:15:00.000 |
| 2010 | 683 | 247910 | 10 | *null* | *null* | 2021-06-20 01:55:00.000 | *null* | *null* |
| 1946 | 980 | 225388 | 3 | *null* | *null* | 2022-03-01 19:28:00.000 | *null* | *null* |
| 1946 | 980 | 225389 | 3 | 8 | 2023-03-01 19:40:00.000 | *null* | 9.00 | 2022-03-01 19:28:00.000 |
| 1946 | 981 | 225390 | 3 | *null* | *null* | 2022-03-03 02:31:00.000 | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tS5P7oBH)

Comment: May I ask why I cant include the LAG() in the SELECT DISTINCT?

Answer (score 2):

If you include `LAG()` under the `SELECT DISTINCT, DISTINCT` will mess up the `ORDER BY` sequence you put it within `LAG()`, making the final result non-ordered, which probably is not what you intend to do.

It makes more sense to perform `LAG()` on the set of unique values after `DISTINCT`.  `DISTINCT` is an aggregate function that returns the set of unique values so it synthesizes/condenses information. Whereas window function (ie. LAG()) retains individual records.

So

```
SELECT *, LAG() OVER (PARTITION BY... ORDER BY ...) AS LagFFArrival
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT
         all the listed columns
      ) AS sub;
```